# Custom route attributes vs parameters in url

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using the following url with a empty category in a web request with angularJS:

```
/api/students/?category=&begin=2&pagesize=3
```

I tried to convert this to Attribute Routing:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "CustomFilter",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{category}/{begin}/{pageSize}",
        defaults: new
        {
            category = RouteParameter.Optional,
            begin = RouteParameter.Optional,
            take = RouteParameter.Optional
        }
    );
```

The first url with an empty parameter seems to work fine, but when I convert it to the attribute routing it does not work when the 'category' parameter is empty. What is the correct way to convert it to attribute routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing in your post is convention-based routing and not attribute routing.

Given this route

```
/api/students/?category=&begin=2&pagesize=3
```

a controller would probably look like this.

```
public StudentsController : ApiController {
    public Students Index(int category, int begin, int pagesize) { ... }
}
```

and route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CustomFilter",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

The binding engine in the framework would match the request: `/api/students/?category=&begin=2&pagesize=3` to `StudentsController.Index` based on the query parameters in the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you have situation when you don't have any of parameter that are in the middle of url you should create another route without this parameter and place it in Routing after existing one.

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "CustomFilter",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{begin}/{pageSize}",
        defaults: new
        {
            begin = RouteParameter.Optional,
            take = RouteParameter.Optional
        }
    );
```